# How to enable Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm running a .Net 4.5 WPF application in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 in a Debug build configuration.

In Tools > Options > Debugging > General I have checked Enable UI Debugging Toos for XAML and Preview selected elements in Live Visual Tree.

However, when I run my application, both the Live Property Explorer and Live Visual Tree Windows display the following message.

UI Debugging is either disabled, not supported by the current application or the application execution is paused.

What am I missing?

Comment: i still recommend using Snoop....

Comment: @CharithJ This question is not a duplicate of the one you mentioned. I have the Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML checked, and Visual Studio is still not displaying them.

Comment: This appears to be something with this particular install of VS. I installed on a different machine and it works with the same solution. I have also upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and it is working now.

Comment: ... or Microsoft have not implemented this functionality properly. If they did you would not be presented with a list of suggestions for when it shows nothing.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue and resolved it by also selecting the "Preview selected elements in Live Visual Tree" sub-option (i.e. under Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable UI Debugging Toos for XAML).  Whenever I unchecked that option, the Live Property Explorer and Live Visual Tree windows would go back to showing the "UI Debugging is either disabled..." message again.

Comment: As of VS2019 16.8 this has been moved to Debugging - Hot Reload - Enable in-app toolbar –

Answer (score 13):

Steps can be seen below, it works well for me.

Open VS, then type "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML" in the **Quick Lanch** box, enter to go to setting detail page (see screenshot below).

- Uncheck "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"
- Check "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML" and its sub options

[image: related_screenShot]

You can refer from **Microsoft**:

[How to: Display WPF Trace Information - Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-display-wpf-trace-information?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio go to Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General 
and uncheck "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and the Live Visual Tree should show up.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing worked for me except for a reboot (log out/in probably would have sufficed). I'm guessing a supporting process got into a bad state and wasn't closing when Visual Studio did.

Answer (score 0):

On my end, the issue was that the **Target device** under the project *Properties\Debug\Start Options* had somehow changed from "Local Machine" to "Simulator". Going back to "Local Machine" (without changing any of the other debug options mentioned in the other answers) brought back the live visual tree and the live property explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause this to fail is security common in a corporate environment.  If the other solutions do not work for you (and your code is not already there), try moving your code to a location under your Documents folder.  There are sometimes exceptions to security constraints on your Documents folder, and those security constraints can keep this feature from working.