# VS 2015 Live Visual Tree Always Blank

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

Question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131143/how-to-enable-live-visual-tree-and-live-property-explorer-in-visual-studio) except that I see nothing in the Live Visual Tree window (for a solution that worked recently).  Another post suggested checking "Enable native code debugging" in the project debug settings.  I've tried that to no avail.

More Suggestions?

Comment: What type of application are you writing - WPF? I seems at one time WPF was the only app that it worked. In my case I am still working with WP8.1 Winrt, and it is blank as well. It probably works great in WP10 I assume.

Comment: It's a mix of WinForms and WPF.  Funky, but as I say, the tree was working recently...

Comment: Works again; no clue why.